# Camera flash blinking stalls app

Tags: java, android, flashlight

I want to add a new feature to my app: I created a progress bar and every time the progress changes, the flash will blink with a delay equal to the value of the progress in milliseconds.

When I modify the progress, the flash begins to blink but I can't do anything until it reaches the number of blinks (20). I want to be able to modify the delay even if the flash is still blinking.

```
private void blink(int sleepMS) throws Exception{

    //int sleepMS=(1/10)*50;
    int flashCount=20;
    getCamera();
    camera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
    camera.startPreview();
    Thread thr = new Thread();
    thr.start();

   for(int i=0;i<flashCount;i++) {
           flipFlash();
           thr.sleep(sleepMS);
           flipFlash();
           thr.sleep(sleepMS);
       }

    camera.stopPreview();
    //camera.release();


}

private void flipFlash(){
    if (isFlashOn) {
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        isFlashOn = false;
    } else{
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        isFlashOn = true;
    }
}
```

Where `getCamera()` gets camera parameters. And the code for the `SeekBar` listener:

```
volumeControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volume_bar);
volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

  int progressChanged = 0;

  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
      progressChanged = progress;

  }

  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

          try {
              blink(100 - progressChanged);
          } catch (Exception e) {

          }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your for loop is on you main thread it is blocking all other operations. From you code, it seems like you meant to do something like this:

```
Thread thr = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<flashCount;i++) {
            flipFlash();
            thr.sleep(sleepMS);
            flipFlash();
            thr.sleep(sleepMS);
        }
    }
});
thr.start();
```